# Load 1000 records with Image to collection view CloudKit Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cloudkit

I have a CloudKit database with over 1000 record (image.jpg ~ 1.0 MB in image Asset)

Should I load Image in CollectionViewCell?

My code is:

```
func loadData(){
        self.loading.startAnimating()
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: self.recordType, predicate: predicate)
        query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "productID", ascending: true)]
        operation.query = query
        operation.resultsLimit = 1000
        operation.qualityOfService = .userInteractive
        operation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record) in
            self.items.append(record)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        operation.queryCompletionBlock = { (queryCursor, error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.loading.stopAnimating()
            }
        }
        myData.add(operation)
    }
```

My CollectionViewCell:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "productCell", for: indexPath)
        let img = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 1, y: 1, width: w - 2, height: h - 2))
        img.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        img.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: (self.items[indexPath.item]["productImage"] as! CKAsset).fileURL.path)
        cell.contentView.addSubview(img)

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: What is your question? Is it whether you should use a `UICollectionView` to display the images? Or do you have any issues with the above code actually not working?

Comment: I'm afraid that with over 1.0 GB to load may be my app will crash. The cells always loading big data. So, should I load Image in cell or load Image to an Array and reload collectionView later?

Comment: Both `UICollectionView` and `UITableView` only load data for the visible cells. So they are not going to load all the data at once. But if your images are big, then they will consume a lot of bandwidth as the user scrolls - if the images have to be downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of fetch 1000 records one time you should fetch a small set each time user scrolls on your UICollectionView.

With this you obtain better performance and recovers only the images that you need.

To do this you must set the `resultsLimit` property to a number that fits with images quantity that shows your CollectionView plus 5 or 6

Each time user reach the end of your CollectionView you should perform another fetch passing the CKQueryCursor as a parameter.